# Need GoLang function declaration explanation

Tags: function, go

I have seen function declaration and usage
https://gobyexample.com/functions

But I have golang code which looks like below:

```
func (channel *AmqpChannel) FunctionName(message string) int {

...
}
```

I am not finding any references to the above mentioned syntax anywhere.

Can someone please explain this syntax of functions in golang.
What I am mainly not getting is (channel *AmqpChannel) part before function name.

Comment: There's one place to look and that's https://golang.org/ref/spec

Comment: Please read [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/) for such basic questions of language syntax. This specific syntax is covered in the section about [methods](https://tour.golang.org/methods/1).

Answer (score 1):

This is a [method declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations) for a method named `FunctionName` defined on a `*AmqpChannel` object.

`(channel *AmqpChannel)` declares this method with a pointer receiver, meaning you should be calling it on an object of type `*AmqpChannel`. This is contrasted to a method with a value receiver declared with `(channel AmqpChannel)`.

Also see the [calls section of the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls) for details on method calls and pointer vs value receivers, including when the compiler will let you call a pointer method on a value type.

Answer (score 1):

Hi This syntax is used to declare methods, which is basically a Function attached to a type

For example you create a something like

```
type Circle struct {
    Radius float64
}
```

Now if you want to make method you simply do

```
func (c Circle) Area() float64 {
    return  PI * c.Radius * c.Radius
}
```

Methods can be both declared with or without reference

if you use

> (c *Circle)

it will pass circle as a reference to function

Now you can call it like

```
var c Circle
c.Radius = 4
fmt.Println(c.Area())
```